# Two identical ERB expressions for different routes yielding different results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, frontend

I'm running into a problem with a Rails 7 app. I have the following routes defined:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # Defines the root path route ("/")
  root "site#index"

  # Routes for rest of site
  get "/site", to: "site#index"
  resources :projects
  resources :coursework
```

The controllers of my models Projects and Courses are both the default as generated by `rails generate controller` (i.e. they both have no actions), and they both have no views in their `app/views/` folders. However, this `index.html.erb` for my `site` will produce an error:

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Minimum Reproducible Example</title>

</head>
<p>
  <%= link_to "View All Courses", :coursework %>
  <%= link_to "View All Projects", :projects %>
</p>
```

`ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Site#index`

`No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"coursework"}, missing required keys: [:id] Did you mean?  coursework_url`

`rails routes` shows both `projects#show` and `coursework#show`.

If I comment out the first link, it will work perfectly (the page will render and View All Projects will error upon being clicked on as expected, as I have not defined an `index` in controller or view). Why would this differ for the two controllers which are identical except in name?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You are running into a rails convention issue --  coursework is singular, not plural and rails is confused.  Change  resources :coursework to resources :courseworks

Comment: @dbugger That works, thanks so much! I'll be refactoring my controller since courseworks isn't a widely-used word, along with some others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `link_to "View All Projects", :projects`, because projects is plural, rails is generating a link to the index route, `/projects`, which works fine.

But with `link_to "View All Courses", :coursework`, since coursework is singular, it is trying to route to the show route, `/coursework/:id`, and failing because an id wasn't provided.

Rails suggests pluralizing your controllers to allow many of these routing niceties to work ([Guide link](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#controller-naming-convention)), so I'd suggest renaming the controller to something like `CourseworksController` or `CoursesController`.